# Podspec and Project version

Tags: ios, cocoapods

How does podspec know what Project version is the most current(stable) one? I am new to cocoapods and trying to understand how podspec keeps up with project versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Podspec represents a single version of a library, which is why they're  tied to a version number. So CocoaPods can look through all of the Podspecs for a CocoaPod and determine the latest by deciding which has the highest version number.